# Batch import of eps inside Openoffice-Writer

Tags: conversion, latex, import, openoffice-writer, eps

I have a huge quantity of `eps` images, generated by another huge quantity of `gnuplot` scripts. Is there a way to import them inside an `Openoffice Writer` document (`.odt`) at once?

I'm about to try [the solution described in this post](http://pastcounts.wordpress.com/2007/10/23/converting-latex-to-openoffice/) ([and also in this one](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=453721)), first writing a script to generate a `latex` document with my `eps` images and then converting it to `odt` with `tex4ht`. This would have the advantage that I could also script the figures caption. However, if there is a simpler way I'd like to test it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I've been able to find is explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75277/avoid-eps-to-png-conversion-using-mk4ht-oolatex). However, `eps` images are converted into `png` format, thus loosing the vector format.

I've been able to uncompress the `odt` file and search/replace (with `sed`) the `png` occurrences with references to `eps` files but this is far from the optimal solution.